# Add data to query results to LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, soql, class

hoping i can get some help on this one:

I have an Apex class where im running a SOQL query:

```
public with sharing class TestClass {

@AuraEnabled
public static List <sobject> getFreqLWC(String ConId)
{//begin method
  try{

      List<sobject> FreqList;
      String query = 'SELECT Account,Id';

      query += 'FROM Contact ';

      query += 'WHERE Id = :ConId ';

      FreqList = Database.query(query);
 
      system.debug('FreqList---->' + FreqList);
      return FreqList;

  }
    
    
  catch(Exception ex){
      system.debug('=== exception =='+ex);
      throw new AuraHandledException('Unable : ' + ex.getMessage() + ' - Line ' + ex.getLineNumber());
  }//close catch92
  }//close method
}//close class
```

This class runs a query for a LWC page i have and returns the results which i then convert to an Excel doc.

I want to send the query that this class constructed as a string to my JS file on LWC. Is that possible?

My ultimate goal is to add some rows to my generated excel at the end where i can provide the query that was submitted for the results on the file.

The way the Excel generates the  file is by converting the query into something like this:

```
[{"Account__c":"a4Q7i000000WxmKEAS",
 "Type__c":"H",
 "Bday__c":"2006-02-12"},
{"Account__c":"a4Q7i0000002WxmKTHS",
 "Type__c":"T",
 "Bday__c":"2013-05-11"}]
```

I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can add some wrapper class with all data you need, like

```
public class FreqLWCResponse {
    public String query;
    public List<SObject> freqList;
}
```

And then populate it and return to your LWC instead of List directly:

```
public with sharing class TestClass {

@AuraEnabled
public static FreqLWCResponse getFreqLWC(String ConId)
{//begin method
  try{

      List<sobject> FreqList;
      String query = 'SELECT Account,Id';

      query += 'FROM Contact ';

      query += 'WHERE Id = :ConId ';

      FreqList = Database.query(query);
 
      system.debug('FreqList---->' + FreqList);
      FreqLWCResponse resp = new FreqLWCResponse();
      resp.query = query;
      resp.freqList = FreqList;
      return resp;

  }
    
    
  catch(Exception ex){
      system.debug('=== exception =='+ex);
      throw new AuraHandledException('Unable : ' + ex.getMessage() + ' - Line ' + ex.getLineNumber());
  }//close catch92
  }//close method
}//close class
```

And then on your LWC instead of accessing list you can access separately response.query and response.freqList

Please mark this as correct answer if it was helpful.

Comment: This almost does it, however, Is there a way i can get the actual translated value of ConId?

Comment: @HermesOmarGomez , sorry, I didn't get you. Translated Id? Translated to what?